# slow touchpad sensitivity

Tags: touchpad

I have recently installed Ubuntu 15.04. But my touchpad sensitivity is low as I searched on internet to increase but those settings are in vain. I also disabled two finger scroll and natural and natural scroll in touchpad setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the oldschool synaptiks touchpad settings manager:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wget gdebi
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/synaptiks/kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb
sudo gdebi kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb
sudo apt-mark hold kde-config-touchpad
```

After installation, open a terminal and execute the following command:

```
synaptiks &
```

You will probably see a bunch of output and then it will exit. After that happens, open a terminal and execute the following command (again) to open the settings configuration:

```
synaptiks &
```

You will probably want to check the box to start up automatically at boot.